# OpenGL: a simple colored triangle glDebugCallback error

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2019

I have an error.

```
// Callback function for OpenGL debug messages 
void glDebugCallback(GLenum sources, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar *msg, const void *userParam)
{
    printf("DEBUG: %s\n", msg);
}

int initGL()
{
    // Register the debug callback function
    glDebugMessageCallback(glDebugCallback, NULL);
```

The error message is

```
E0167   argument of type "void (*)(GLenum sources, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar *msg, const void *userParam)" is incompatible with parameter of type "GLDEBUGPROC"
```

I use VS2019, Windows 10 OpenGL 4.6

Comment: See [Function unable to match GLDEBUGPROC, only on MSVC (uses same glew version 2.1.0, on linux with gcc/clang it's fine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755492/function-unable-to-match-gldebugproc-only-on-msvc-uses-same-glew-version-2-1-0)